# C# selenium alternative with JS loading

Tags: c#, selenium, parsing, web, dynamic

I am writing web parser using C# and my selenium code works just fine for 10-15 minutes and after that i get ban from server, i do not ddos site or some kind of that, and it works +- human like speed. im trying to find out is probllem in speed or in detecting bot on site some other way. Thats why my question **is there some kind of alternative that loads**

***dynamic js elements* ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your automation code wont affect your speed for the flow you are carrying out.
If it works fine in the first instance with a particular speed- it will work same for every run; unless performance of the site is not same as before.

There are few sites enabled with bot detection functionality. These function analyze the speed and behavior of the flow that user is being carried out on the site.
In your case- I think site has bot detection enabled and your execution speed gets lowered in lateral instance.

If your flow surpasses dynamic elements in first instance- It has to pass in next run too.

Hope this helps.